# Proving continuity of eigenfunction

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I have a matrix that looks like a discrete Laplacian. Now I can plot the entries of the eigenvector by their index on the x axis and value on the y-axis. Now increasing the size of the matrix makes the datapoints look like a function i.e. plotting eigenvector as a function. Now in the large matrix size limit, how do I show that this actually converges to the eigenfunction of the continuous operator and the eigenfunction is continuous? Is there some theorem showing this?

Example:

[image: This is matrix]

[image: Plotted eigenvector]

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi, I added an example

Comment: You say "the" eigenvector, but which one among all of them ? The eigenvector associated with the highest or with the lowest eigenvalue ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Highest eigenvalue

Comment: 1) Have you attempted to replace all $-1.967$ values by $-2$ plainly ? 2) Why is your matrix beginning by a line of zeros ? I would be desirable to have a north-western corner symmetrical of the south-eastern one.

Comment: @JeanMarie In the problem I'm studying, the structure is not as symmetric as what you're suggesting, hence the modified matrix. But regardless of these symmetry concerns, there should be a way to show that for all matrix operators of some class, their largest eigenvectors must converge to continuous function in large matrix size limit?

Comment: It seems like all these matrices converge to some nice operators. Discontinuity of eigenfunctions happen only when there is some delta function as well, which might not be the case here.

Comment: I agree with the term "class of matrices" : this is why I suggested to study one of the "most representative" matrix in this class, i.e. the most symmetric matrix, in order to study its dominant eigenvector, getting (if possible) exact entries of this eigenvector in order to be able to conclude at least in this case.

Comment: Perhaps some kind of [von Neumann stability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) would be helpful here

Comment: @Razor In general, you should be looking for ways to demonstrate that the finite difference approximation scheme is **numerically stable**. I suspect you can find some general statement in a textbook that is applicable here

Comment: Could you give the value of the dominant eigenvalue in the case you have shown ? I think I have an idea.

Comment: What is "the continuous operator" in your question?

Comment: Could you give the list of eigenvalues of the matrix ?

Comment: "handwave reasoning" : Let us replace matrix $A$ by its opposite matrix $B=-A$, positive definite matrix having positive eigenvalues. Equation $BV = \lambda V$ "is" the convolution $[1,-2,1]\star V \approx \lambda V$ ; but this convolution with $V$ is the second (discrete) derivative $\Delta^2 V=\lambda V$ : having a vector proportional to its second derivative means that its components have the form $V_k=e^{ak}+bk+c$ (with $a=\sqrt{\lambda}$). This would coincide with your results (don't forget to take opposite values when coming back to $A$) with $b=0, c=-0.2735...$.

Comment: Of course, this has to be "rigorized", in particular by taking into account boundary conditions.

Comment: Correction to a previous remark : In fact $a=\pm \sqrt{\lambda}$ and we consider case $a=-\sqrt{\lambda}$

Comment: Using the "eigenvalues" formula for a tridiagonal matrix [here] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) the eigenvalues should not be far from $\lambda_k = -2 + 2 \cos (k \pi/(n+1))=-4 \cos^2 (k \pi/(n+1)), k=1 \cdots n$ (remark :  $-4 < \lambda_k < 0$) with $n=17$.

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your comments. I apologise for the delay. You want to show that $V_k$ has a smooth functional form to show continuity? Makes sense. I'm trying how to modify the guess solution of $V_k$ slightly to incorporate the terms in between (-1.967).

Comment: @BobTerrell Laplacian with a constant potential hump in a region.